# MemoryOutError in lower config phones

Tags: android

I have developed one Ecom application in which i am using Picasso Lib for image caching, paging for loading 20-20 products in one category within same adapter. This application is working fine on high configuration phone, But some times application get outMemoryError on some screens and application hugs and crashes. I am not sure what i am doing wrong and why i am getting this error. Can some one please advice how to resolve this issue or how to track this issue on Android studio.Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. you can use square's leak canary to detect memory leak in your app
2. change Picasso with facebook's fresco, since the both image library have different method to deal with limited memory

Answer (score 0):

use square's leak canary  ,a  memory leak detection library for Android and Java.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary